Nautilus not displaying previews for images, but for video/pdf it is working
Nautilus did not load any previews for images and videos. After installing some thumbnailers like ffmpegthumbnailer and evince-thumbnailer, I do have previews for videos and PDF files, but still not for any images.
I tried a lot of the advice from all kinds of stackexchange posts on this topic, like removing the entire ~/.cache/thumbnails folder, checking the thumbnailing settings of nautilus with dconf-editor, checking global thumbnailing settings in dconf-editor. Everything is set up correctly, but still no image thumbnails.
[edit]
I switched to Ubuntu last year, so the version that I installed at the time was 23.04. Now I am on 23.10. The problem persisted ever since I use Ubuntu.

In my case I was able to hunt down the problem by restarting nautilus in debug mode:
Paste this into the terminal.
nautilus -q
G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all NAUTILUS_DEBUG=Window nautilus

Somewhere in the messages there was a WARNING:
(org.gnome.Nautilus:34905): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: 14:06:33.878: Failed to load thumbnailer from "/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer": Die Schlüsselwertedatei enthält die Zeile »image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;«, welche kein zulässiges Schlüssel-Wert-Paar, keine Gruppe und kein Kommentar ist

What this says is: All thumbnailing programs need to have a .thumbnail file in /usr/share/thumbnailers, to register the image types they will process and to say where the program is residing.
The program responsible for generating image previews in the GNOME desktop environment is gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer. In its respective .thumbnail file, the MIME types (image formats) that should be handled by this thumbnailer, are specified.
cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer

returns:
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=image/png;image/jpeg;image/bmp;image/x-bmp;image/x-MS-bmp;image/gif;image/x-icon;image/x-ico;image/x-win-bitmap;image/vnd.microsoft.icon;application/ico;image/ico;image/icon;text/ico;application/x-navi-animation;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/tiff;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-tga;image/x-icns;image/x-quicktime;image/qtif;
image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;

As the WARNING above said in German: The last line is invalid, because it is no key-value pair and it is just the continuation of the above MimeType-value. Therefore, the whole thumbnailing program ceases to work. Fix this by appending the last line to the MimeType=-value with your favourite text editor (you will need root privileges):
sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer

afterwards, the file looks like this for me:
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=image/png;image/jpeg;image/bmp;image/x-bmp;image/x-MS-bmp;image/gif;image/x-icon;image/x-ico;image/x-win-bitmap;image/vnd.microsoft.icon;application/ico;image/ico;image/icon;text/ico;application/x-navi-animation;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/tiff;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-tga;image/x-icns;image/x-quicktime;image/qtif;image/x-3fr;image/x-adobe-dng;image/x-arw;image/x-bay;image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-crw;image/x-cap;image/x-cr2;image/x-crw;image/x-dcr;image/x-dcraw;image/x-dcs;image/x-dng;image/x-drf;image/x-eip;image/x-erf;image/x-fff;image/x-fuji-raf;image/x-iiq;image/x-k25;image/x-kdc;image/x-mef;image/x-minolta-mrw;image/x-mos;image/x-mrw;image/x-nef;image/x-nikon-nef;image/x-nrw;image/x-olympus-orf;image/x-orf;image/x-panasonic-raw;image/x-panasonic-raw2;image/x-pef;image/x-pentax-pef;image/x-ptx;image/x-pxn;image/x-r3d;image/x-raf;image/x-raw;image/x-rw2;image/x-rwl;image/x-rwz;image/x-samsung-srw;image/x-sigma-x3f;image/x-sony-arw;image/x-sony-sr2;image/x-sony-srf;image/x-sr2;image/x-srf;image/x-x3f;

This is my personal fix, I hope it will help somebody struggling with the same issue.
